# window.location.pathname problem in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to have some conditional rendering. I don't want to render Navbar and Drawer components if the pathname is '/' or if the pathname is not defined in the routes file. When routes is not defined I have a special 404 not found page and that is only what I want there. So if pathname is === routes.path and pathname !== '/' only in that case I want my Navbar and Drawer. My code currently works, but on pages where U should see them, U must reload the page.

```
import UnknownRoute from "../components/UnknownRoute/UnknownRoute";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "../helpers/routes";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Drawer from "../components/Drawer/Drawer";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Mainlayout = () => {
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState("/");
  console.log(loc);
  const getRoutes = (routes) => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      return <Route path={prop.path} key={key} element={<prop.element />} />;
    });
  };

  const unknownRoute = () => {
    return <Route path="*" element={<UnknownRoute />} />;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoc(window.location.pathname);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      {routes.map((route) =>
        route.path !== "/"
          ? loc === route.path && (
              <div>
                <Navbar />
                <Drawer />
              </div>
            )
          : undefined
      )}

      <Routes>
        {getRoutes(routes)} {unknownRoute()}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mainlayout;
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]. Without seeing the actual code causing you a problem I don't think we can provide an answer, only guesses.

Comment: Tangentially related, but it seems like it might be an XY problem as well—using the pathname when there’s already the router and route components would make relying on the pathname more brittle than other mechanisms.

Comment: You're only setting `loc` once, when the component first mounts. This is why you don't see a change until a refresh. There's no reason to put that in state in the first place. Just use `window.location.pathname` directly where you need it.

Comment: @BrianThompson I did it , but result is same. I must reload page if I want to see Navbar or Drawer let say on About page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating a simple thing. `react-router-dom@6` already has a mechanism for "conditionally" rendering routed content in the form of [layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes).

Create a layout route component that renders the `Navbar` and `Drawer` components along with an `Outlet` for the nested routes you want to render with them.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "../helpers/routes";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Drawer from "../components/Drawer/Drawer";
import UnknownRoute from "../components/UnknownRoute/UnknownRoute";

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Drawer />
    </div>
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const Mainlayout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={/* place home page component here */} />

        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          ... routes that render w/ Navbar and Drawer
          {routes.map((prop, key) => (
            <Route path={prop.path} key={key} element={<prop.element />} />
          ))}
        </Route>

        ... routes that render w/o Navbar and Drawer
        <Route path="*" element={<UnknownRoute />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mainlayout;
```

If you don't want to go the route of using a layout route, then use the [`useMatch` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usematch) with a matcher for the home `"/"` path.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate, useMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "../helpers/routes";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Drawer from "../components/Drawer/Drawer";
import UnknownRoute from "../components/UnknownRoute/UnknownRoute";

const Mainlayout = () => {
  const isHome = useMatch("/"); // returns null for non-match

  const getRoutes = (routes) => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      return <Route path={prop.path} key={key} element={<prop.element />} />;
    });
  };

  const unknownRoute = () => {
    return <Route path="*" element={<UnknownRoute />} />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      {!isHome && (
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Drawer />
        </div>
      )}

      <Routes>
        {getRoutes(routes)}
        {unknownRoute()}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mainlayout;
```